# Robocopy issues with symbolic links and output log file

Tags: robocopy

I'm trying to robocopy these folders for a Windows 10 system drive I attached externally):

- The full User's folder
- The full Windows folder

I know more or less how to do it, but my doubts are these:

- Can I output skipped files and folders only to a log file?  (files or folders that could not be copied through due to some issue), I don't need to see files copied in the log, only those that were not copied  for some reason, if that is possible.
- Can I copy offline files, symbolic links and directories (not the targets), I noticed robocopy usually hangs on these, why is this?  I want those offline and symbolic links too, so I don't have to revise why there are missing files and folders afterwards.

I guess this cannot be done, but thought it might be worth asking.

Any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

#### Can I output skipped files and folders only to a log file?

This is not possible.

#### Can I copy offline files, symbolic links and directories?

Use the `/sl` option - Copy file symbolic links instead of the target.

> `sl` Will copy symbolic links, this will copy a File Symbolic Link only, creating a new symbolic link at the destination.

> For a Directory Symbolic Link, a Junction, or a Hard Link, `RoboCopy` will follow the source and copy the contents to a standard folder in the destination. For a backup program this is usually the desired behaviour.

Notes:

- You can't copy offline files.
- You also can't files that are in use, so that is something else for you to consider.

  > Robocopy will fail to copy files that are locked by other users or applications, so limiting the number of retries with /R:0 will speed up copying by skipping any in-use files. The Windows Volume Shadow Copy service is the only Windows subsystem that can copy open files.

Source [Robocopy "Robust File Copy" - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Comment: To start with: Super thanks for your answer.

Sorry, I still don’t get it:

I would like to know why Directory Symbolic Links, Junctions and Hard Links cannot be copied, are they not they files after all?, even if they are just empty files that point to other files that no longer exist in destination..

My objective is to copy EVERYTHING from source to destination, EVEN IF IT IS USELESS, including these “pointer” files and folders, so that I can compare the number of files and folders and overall size without getting a mismatch (such as when comparing with File Explorer).

Comment: Robocopy is not designed to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I made a list of what Robocopy copies over compared with copy-pasting with File Explorer in Windows 10:

I included only some significant items that you may doubt if it gets copied:

https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?resid=DD9BE0DD387BA118!15247&ithint=file%2cxlsx&authkey=!AHFCASo7_FreprU